# Is there an update of Jcoverflip Jquery plugin to fix compatibility with jquery-ui-1.8.+.js?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

With jquery-ui-1.7.x.js version works fine, but with newer version 1.8.x it gives me error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'widget'

From what I saw in jquery ui downloads before 1.8 version there is no option to download "Widget" but in 1.8 you have a selection to download core and widget seperately. There is I believe the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author has developped a more compatible version of JCoverFlip with jQuery UI 1.8 at https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip.

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, [SlidingGallery](http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx) would be an alternative.

Answer (score -2):

Try the jquery 1.3.2 version and it works fine!